# How to easily create PSObject from function arguments to return result to pipeline?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, pipeline, psobject

Currently I'm doing like that:

```
function Invoke-Service
{
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [int] $Id,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string] $Name,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [int] $Age
    )
    DoSomeWork |
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Id = $Id; Name = $Name; Age = $Age }
}
```

This function can obtain it's parameters directly or from `Import-Csv` output, or `select` output.

But very often I want to continue processing down the pipeline with all the power of `PSObject`:

```
Import-Csv -Path "data.csv" |
    Invoke-Service |
        ... #
```

And my question is: do I need to call `New-Object` enumerating all parameters or is there a keyword or other technique which I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$PSBoundParameters` variable:

```
New-Object psobject -Property $PSBoundParameters
```

`$PSBoundParameters` is an automatic variable that contains a hashtable with an entry per named parameter, using the full parameter name as the key and the parameter argument as the value, so in your example it's already 100% aligned with the input you're trying to pass

Comment: Works not only with parameters from pipeline (if someone doubts). Great!